# Error message "failed to download repository information" when attempting to check for updates via update manager

Tags: upgrade

[image]

This comes up sometimes when I attempt to check for updates. I have been trying to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10, but I have been unsuccessful, due to the fact that Update Manager is not giving me the option to upgrade.

Comment: Do you use a proxy server for internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
sudo apt-get update
```

alternately you can go into Software Center and select Software Sources, select Other Software and remove the conflicting ppa's.

The first option worked on a friends system when he couldn't update his system.
Option 2 i recently did when I started constantly having issues with PlayDeb.net being unresponsive. Hope this was some what helpful